# Undeterministic black second screen [Ubuntu 15.10, Dell Latitude 3340 (hdmi) -> IIyama (vga)]

Tags: unity, 15.10, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga

**Problem:**

My second screen works most of the time fine, but sometimes it turns to black and is then difficult to get it back working. This behavior seems semi-random, that is why I find it difficult to search for a solution. Also it is important to note that this behavior only seems to happen with my  screen and not with projectors for example.

I say semi-random because it often (but not always) happens when I logout/restart/start a new program. These actions also often (again not always) tend to turn the screen on again.

**example:**

I start my pc up and everything works fine. Then after doing some work for some time:

I start a program/do nothing special/logout/...

and my second screen goes black, saying it does not get any input. Then after **repeatedly** logging out/in or (un)plugging the HDMI cable it goes back online again. This repeats itself from time to time and drives me crazy, I really do not have a clue what it could be, hope you guys can help me!

**Setup:**

I have Ubuntu 15.10 running on a dell latitude 3340 with HDMI output and also an IIyama screen with VGA input. I connect my screen with an HDMI to VGA converter.

Comment: Hard to say. My guess is your HDMI cable, the problem you describe is common whit HDMI cables and the solution is to unplug and plug back in.

Comment: That could be it of course, but the fact that I use that same HDMI cable for presentations (the projector I use also has only a VGA input), and it works fine then makes me doubt it.  I also tried multiple different VGA cables and the problem still persists..  Furthermore logging in/out often causes/solves the problem, and then I do not touch the cable. So I doubt the problem is in the cables I use.

Comment: Well it is not the cable exactly. They tell me static electricity builds up on the connection. At any rate, this is a common problem. http://bfy.tw/5jBo

Answer (score 0):

If the HDMI cable is not the issue, it could also be worth while to upgrade to a more recent video driver.

There should be options for upgrading Your driver here: https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-installer-linux-1.4.0

Comment: Thanks for providing the link, I will try it out. I always had the assumption ubuntu "automatically" made sure I have the latest driver. But apparently this is not always the case?

Comment: Far from it. Even the open source drivers are usually fairly outdated, so I would definitely be worth a try... It should be said that I have very little experience with Intel graphics drivers on Ubuntu myself, so You may need to ask another question, if You run into problems.

Comment: Ok, interesting to know. Do you perhaps know what the reason is that these drivers are so outdated?